# Grails GORM on multiple Forms

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

Usually I'm using One-to-many relationship by this way :

```
class Study {
    static hasMany = [ crfs : Crf ]
    String name 
    ...
} 

class Crf { 
String title
String info 
...
}
```

I can extend this relationship to others domains, Ex :

```
static hasMany = [ crfs : Crf, crfb : CrfBlood ...]
```

But in my case I have to link the Study domain to 30 others domains, maybe more...(ex : CrfBlood, CrfMedical, crfFamily, etc...).

What domain model implementation should I use in my case ?
I would like to keep the dynamic finders usability in my project.

**Update - model complement :**

A **Study** can have one-to-many **Subject**.
A **Study** can have one-to-many **Crfs** (ex : CrfBlood, CrfMedical, crfFamily, etc...).
A **Subject** can have one-to-many **Visit** (ex : a subject can have several Blood testing).

I would like to dynamically assign Crfs to a Study, so how can I use GORM (dynamic finders) without using static hasMany = [...] in my domain ?
Maybe, I can implement a service to do the same stuff did by hasMany ?

Comment: What's the problem having 30 domain classes in `hasMany`? Are all the relationships 1:M (maybe `blood` is 1:1 relationship)?

Comment: I could have for some crfs with 1:1 relationship. Usually it would be 1:M.

Comment: so there's some "hasOne" relationship: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/hasOne.html . But.. what's so bad with hasMany? Why don't you just use it?

Comment: Each time I'm adding a new crf, I have to update the Study domain. Also, for each Study an administrator must define which crfs he wants to use for the study (for example : Study1 only use CrfBlood and CrfMedical, whereas Study2 use only CrfMedical and CrfFamily).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare all Crf types as subclasses of `Crf`, so that you'll only have one relationship to `Study`, but still be able to add the different types.

```
class Crf {
    String title
    String info
}

class CrfBlood extends Crf {
    String detailBlood
}

class CrfMedical extends Crf {
    String detailMedical
}

class Study {
    String name
    static hasMany = [ crfs: Crf ]
}
```

Then you can do:

```
def s = new Study(...)
def c1 = new CrfBlood(...)
def c2 = new CrfMedical(...)
s.addToCrfs(c1)
s.addToCrfs(c2)
```

Comment: Oh, I can use table per sub-class instead of table per hierarchy. static mapping = {
   tablePerHierarchy false
}